1940 to 1955 film noir involving heist and masked or hooded men unknown to one another
Could anyone help remind me of a 1940 to 1955 film noir, black and white film I would like to re-watch.

Black and white
40's to mid 50's
Involves a heist or robbery
I think in the opening scene there is a skill tester pretty much the same as the ones we have today with the dangling claw (however I've been on a noir bent and may be confusing this part).

The main plot of the movie, though, is a heist, and everyone is made to wear a mask or bag over their heads to hide identity. I think none of the gang of thieves knows the others or the person who hired them. The main character flees to Mexico for a while, and then ends up at some kind of resort where I'm sure some more shenanigans ensue.
At one point the robbers are on some kind of speed boat. As always there is a gorgeous female love interest. There is a policeman or a detective on their trail also. Plenty of scenes are shot around the resort complex, and at some stage in the night at the complex there is a shoot out or someone gets murdered. 
It's a film that I found on a recommended noir list some time ago, so it should be semi well known.
It's definitely an American production.

This sounds like Kansas City Confidential (1952) with John Payne & Colleen Grey
Wikipedia

A nameless, ruthless man (Preston Foster) who identifies himself as Mr. Big is timing to the minute the arrival of two trucks. One is an armored car routinely picking up bags containing lots of money from a bank. The other truck delivers to a flower shop next door. The man’s timing shows that, for a very few minutes, the schedule of both trucks coincidentally parks them next to each other. He is casing the armored car. He needs a gang to help him rob it. He selects three men for the gang—the addictive gambler Peter Harris (Jack Elam) wanted for murder, gum-chewing thug Boyd Kane (Neville Brand) and the womaniziing Tony Romano (Lee Van Cleef). When interviewing them, he wears a mask so they cannot identify him. He has selected them because each has a reason for fleeing the US. 



The robbery and pursuit go just as Mr. Big has planned. Each wearing a mask so none can identify each other, he and his gang arrive in a look-alike floral truck as Rolfe, unaware, drives away.



Rolfe pursues him to Tijuana and looks for him in illegal gambling joints. Finding Harris, Rolfe follows him to his hotel room and, finding the mask Harris wore, beats him into revealing the Mexican resort of Barados as the gang’s meeting place.



Foster is now ready to carry out the double-cross. He writes individual notes to Rolfe, Kane, and Romano to meet him on his boat, the Manana, where the three will all coincidentally be, ripe for pickup by the police. Before that can happen, Kane and Romano try to ambush Rolfe, who gets the drop on them, admits he’s Rolfe, not Harris, and makes them believe he’s after Harris’ share. At the same time, Helen tells her father she knows Rolfe is in trouble. Once again, he fails to persuade her to stop seeing Rolfe.
Kane and Romano are not finished with Rolfe. They waylay Rolfe and discover he’s going to the boat. All three are driven there by Foster, who they still don’t know is Mr. Big. On board the boat, Rolfe escapes and finds the stolen money in a cabinet. Romano, gun in hand, confronts him. Rolfe shows him where the money is. Romano, greedy, kills Kane and is ready to take all the money and kill Rolfe, but Foster, trying to save his unraveling plan, intervenes. But he slips and reveals he is Mr. Big. In a resulting gun battle, Foster kills Romano but not before Romano shoots him.





This is the one brilliant :)
